# When start nuxt apps from their parent folder /home using pm2, I get the error "No build files found in /home/.nuxt/dist/server"

Tags: nuxt.js, pm2

Inside my `/home` folder I have 2 nuxt apps, `callh` & `callr`.

```
ff373b7ddfdb:/home# ls
callh                ecosystem.config.js                  startup.sh           callr
```

I can start them each by cd into their own folder and run npm start but I want to use pm2 to start them both, so in `ecosystem.config.js` I write: `'./callh/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js' ...` .

But pm2 report `error FATAL  No build files found in /home/.nuxt/dist/server`. How do I let nuxt server know the codes are in `/home/callh/.nuxt/dist/server` NOT `/home/.nuxt/dist/server` ?

```
2023-12-14 17:25:04:   Use either nuxt build or builder.build() or start nuxt in development mode.
2023-12-14 17:25:04:   at VueRenderer._ready (callh/node_modules/@nuxt/vue-renderer/dist/vue-renderer.js:550:13)
2023-12-14 17:25:04:   at async Server.ready (callh/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:451:5)
2023-12-14 17:25:04:   at async Nuxt._init (callh/node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:344:7)
2023-12-14 17:25:04:
2023-12-14 17:25:04:
2023-12-14 17:25:04:  FATAL  No build files found in /home/.nuxt/dist/server.
2023-12-14 17:25:04: Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.
```

--- update ---

I find a workaround, cd into each sub-folder to run pm2 (change ecosystem.config.js accordingly), so my startup.sh changed to

```
#before it is just pm2 start ecosystem.config.js to start them all together.

cd /home/callh
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
cd /home/callr
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

`ecosystem.config.js` changed to

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'call history ',
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: 'start',
      watch: false,
      ...
```

Thanks to pm2, even I run it twice, there is just one pm2 process.

Comment: Could you pls share your `package.json`?

Comment: But there is nothing special about my nuxt(2) apps , I just create them using create-nuxt-app.

Comment: I guess you want to run two nuxt2 projects on one server at the same time, and you want to manage the processes via pm2, am I right?

Comment: @DengSihan check my answer, thanking for not letting me delete my question and figured out the answer in the end.

Answer (score 1):

After I found the workaround I suddenly realize the correct way to use pm2 in my case is to use [`cwd` property in `ecosystem.config.js`](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/) and put `ecosystem.config.js` in parent folder.

```
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'callh',
      cwd: './callh', //set it or I will get "No build files found"
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: 'start',
      env:{
            NODE_ENV: "production"
            ...
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'callr',
      cwd: './callr',
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: 'start',
      env:{
            NODE_ENV: "production"
            ...
      }
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Good to see the answer that you figured out by yourself, I commented since I've seen you before in the [politics stack](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81140/apart-from-censorship-how-does-the-chinese-government-control-the-media), sorry for not being able to help